# proper place to insert iframe in html

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

I have an iframe element which I create dynamically. Where should I append this iframe if I am not sure if there is a body tag in the html or not ? I was thinking of appending this as child of html tags like div which I have to create dynamically too. But I need to append the div somewhere. Again I am not sure where to append the div.

Comment: Why their is not a `body` tag inside HTML.

Comment: I have to incorporate the iframe in third party code. In rare cases, I have found that the body tag is not there.

Comment: When there is no body tag, browsers will create a body element. But modification of body from inside a nested element throws operation aborted error in IE7. Please see this post- http://www.jspatterns.com/the-ridiculous-case-of-adding-a-script-element/

Comment: Check the below code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert it in a body tag. So if there is no body tag, just insert a body tag after the head element, and the iframe tag in the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you must do it like this.

Check if `body` exists, If it does not exists create it.

```
var dom = document.implementation.createDocument('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'html', null);
if(!document.body)
{
    var body = dom.createElement("body");
    body.innerHTML = "<iframe></iframe>";
    dom.firstChild.appendChild(body);
}
else
{
document.body.innerHTML = "<iframe></iframe>";
}
```

Comment: What if the body is not there due to poor html and creating one makes it even poorer?

Comment: If their is no body then their is nothing to make it poor. It will just create `<body>...</body>` inside `<html>`. Its not gonna make it poor.

Comment: Body tags - if there are divs without body tag they will be pushed under the body tags

Comment: Why their will be div without body tag, who does that?

Comment: Happens all the time - I suspect that is what the question is all about. Why would OP need to add an frame to a completely empty page?

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be asking how to accommodate non-standard HTML documents. If you absolutely must, and cannot insist that the document provider make their documents standards-compliant, I would check for a `body` tag and, if present, append to that. If not available, I'd test for the `html` element and append to that. Beyond that, I'd decline to serve the other party in this regard.

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')) {
    ...
} else if {document.getElementsByTagName('html')) {
    ...
} else {
    console.log("We're sorry, but your document is poorly constructed 
      and we won't be serving you today.");
}
```